# Find the domain of the given function $f(x) =\sqrt{\sin(x) +\sqrt{\sin(x) +\cdots}} $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, functions

> Find the domain of the given function: 
>   $f(x) =\sqrt{\sin(x) +\sqrt{\sin(x) +...}} $

Can we use  the fact that : $ f^2(x)=\sin(x) +f(x) $?

Comment: It seems that $f(x)$ is not well-defined...

Comment: @ xskxzr, Please explain more?

Comment: There are issues with the problem statement, since the formula given for $f(x)$ does not describe a function. $\cdots$ symbols are tricky. I may be able to write an answer later.

Comment: @ aschepler, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and by quadratic equation we get that

$$f_\pm(x) = \frac{1}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\sin x}$$

but since $f$ is the end result of a square root, we get that $f(x) = f_+(x)$. This gives us that

$$\sin x \geq -\frac{1}{4}$$

which happens on $\left[-\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right), \pi + \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\right]$ and any interval $2\pi$ away.

Comment: It's not clear why $f(x) = f_+ (x)$. Why not $f(x) = f_+(x)$ for some $x$ and $f(x) = f_- (x)$ for other $x$? How can we even decide if $f(0)=0$ or $f(0)=1$?

Comment: @aschleper, because $f(x)$ goes under the square root in $\infty$.